# SQL Server query remove overlapping

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with this structure:

```
Create table Test_Table
(
    ID  INT not null Primary key,
    UserID          INT,
    ProjectID       INT,
    StartDate       DateTime,
    EndDate         DateTime,
    CreationDate    DateTime,
    Modifieddate    dateTime
)
GO
```

And sample data like this:

```
Insert Into Test_Table 
values(1,1,10,'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000','2016-01-31 00:00:00.000','2016-01-20 07:33:36.000','2016-01-28 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(2,2,12,'2016-01-02 00:00:00.000','2016-01-29 00:00:00.000','2016-01-18 07:33:36.000','2016-01-25 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(3,3,18,'2016-02-14 00:00:00.000','2016-02-27 00:00:00.000','2016-02-28 07:33:36.000','2016-03-10 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(4,4,21,'2016-01-19 00:00:00.000','2016-02-18 00:00:00.000','2016-02-10 07:33:36.000','2016-02-28 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(5,5,31,'2016-01-10 00:00:00.000','2016-01-28 00:00:00.000','2016-03-10 07:33:36.000','2016-02-27 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(6,5,31,'2016-01-18 00:00:00.000','2016-01-22 00:00:00.000','2016-01-20 07:33:36.000','2016-01-22 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(7,5,31,'2016-01-15 00:00:00.000','2016-02-02 00:00:00.000','2016-02-01 07:33:36.000','2016-02-10 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(8,5,31,'2016-02-10 00:00:00.000','2016-02-25 00:00:00.000','2016-02-20 07:33:36.000','2016-03-03 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(9,5,31,'2016-02-14 00:00:00.000','2016-03-10 00:00:00.000','2016-02-05 07:33:36.000',NULL)

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(10,5,31,'2016-01-14 00:00:00.000','2016-03-31 00:00:00.000','2016-02-12 07:33:36.000','2016-03-01 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(11,6,32,'2016-03-14 00:00:00.000','2016-03-30 00:00:00.000','2016-03-25 07:33:36.000','2016-03-28 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(12,6,15,'2016-03-02 00:00:00.000','2016-03-25 00:00:00.000','2016-03-12 07:33:36.000','2016-02-10 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(13,9,16,'2016-02-12 00:00:00.000','2016-03-15 00:00:00.000','2016-02-24 07:33:36.000','2016-03-12 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(14,12,18,'2016-03-03 00:00:00.000','2016-03-26 00:00:00.000','2016-03-12 07:33:36.000','2016-03-29 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(15,13,22,'2016-04-10 00:00:00.000','2016-05-31 00:00:00.000','2016-05-21 07:33:36.000',NULL)

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(16,12,18,'2016-03-08 00:00:00.000','2016-03-25 00:00:00.000','2016-04-20 07:33:36.000','2016-03-10 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(17,13,41,'2016-02-09 00:00:00.000','2016-02-28 00:00:00.000','2016-02-11 07:33:36.000','2016-03-11 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(18,21,42,'2016-03-07 00:00:00.000','2016-03-27 00:00:00.000','2016-03-12 07:33:36.000','2016-02-23 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(19,23,42,'2016-02-02 00:00:00.000','2016-02-26 00:00:00.000','2016-02-12 07:33:36.000','2016-02-20 00:02:52.943')

Insert Into Test_Table 
values(20,21,43,'2016-03-13 00:00:00.000','2016-03-25 00:00:00.000','2016-03-13 07:33:36.000','2016-03-30 00:02:52.943')
```

Now, I want to remove the overlapping records of startdate and enddate against user's multiple alloction.

Overlapping to be checked at userid/projectid.

For example:

```
Allocation 1 : 1st Jan - 31st Jan
Allocation 2:  2nd Jan – 28th Jan
Allocation 3 : 5th Jan – 27th Jan
Allocation 4:  15th Jan – 2nd Feb
```

In above case allocations 1 to 3 are overlapping whereas 4th one is not.

So if any user having multiple allocation, then fetch the record with max date of CreationDate or ModifiedDate.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Test_Table AS a
    LEFT JOIN Test_Table AS b ON a.UserID = b.UserID AND a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID AND a.StartDate > b.StartDate AND a.EndDate < b.EndDate
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

What the above query does is joins the table to itself to catch cases where A time span is "inside" B timespan. The WHERE clase exludes all these cases, so that only records that are not inclosed in another time span are left.
If you need to exclude duplicate ranges use >= and <=